# Does the UID of a user in Firebase Auth Change?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

So I am working on a project using Firebase Auth, and the structure of the project requires that there is a unique ID for each user because other information associated with the user can change but the structure of the project requires that there is a unique identification for each user that remains constant through out the lifetime of the user or the document associated with the user in this case, so I chose to use the **user UID** generated by firebase auth as the constant ID but I want to know if the **user UID** can be used? I checked through the firebase docs but there was no where stated that the user UID remains unchanged through out the lifetime of the signed user, this is a concern as the users will be able to change basic information like email and password.
so my question is does the **user UID** remain unchanged through out the lifetime of the signed up user even after updates?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIDs assigned by Firebase to a specific account can never change over time.

Comment: thanks for clarifying :D